# Exception when saving document to DB

Tags: android, exception, couchbase-lite

I'm using lite core 2.0.0-DB019, it happens when multiple saves are called in a row, (like saving 100+ docs..). The function is synchronized by the way.
the exception is :

> 11-10 18:10:19.547 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:
>   CouchbaseLiteException{domain=1, code=25, msg=must be called during a
>   transaction} 11-10 18:10:19.548 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.couchbase.lite.internal.bridge.LiteCoreBridge.convertException(LiteCoreBridge.java:22)
>   11-10 18:10:19.548 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.couchbase.lite.Document.save(Document.java:510) 11-10 18:10:19.548
>   5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.couchbase.lite.Document.save(Document.java:424) 11-10 18:10:19.548
>   5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.couchbase.lite.Database.save(Database.java:245) 11-10 18:10:19.548
>   5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.myapp.db.LayersCouchDBHandler.insert(LayersCouchDBHandler.java:165)
>   11-10 18:10:19.548 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.myapp.db.LayersContentProvider.insert(LayersContentProvider.java:348)
>   11-10 18:10:19.548 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.myapp.db.LayersContentProvider.update(LayersContentProvider.java:251)
>   11-10 18:10:19.548 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:356)
>   11-10 18:10:19.548 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:222)
>   11-10 18:10:19.549 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565) 11-10 18:10:19.549
>   5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err: Caused by:
>   LiteCoreException{domain=1, code=25, msg=must be called during a
>   transaction} 11-10 18:10:19.549 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:
>   at com.couchbase.litecore.C4Document.create2(Native Method) 11-10
>   18:10:19.549 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.couchbase.litecore.C4Database.create(C4Database.java:225) 11-10
>   18:10:19.549 5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.couchbase.lite.Document.save(Document.java:608) 11-10 18:10:19.549
>   5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.couchbase.lite.Document.save(Document.java:506) 11-10 18:10:19.549
>   5787-5799/com.myapp W/System.err:     ... 8 more